# Are there any instances of someone other than Eliyahu Hanavi who built a mizbeach after the beit hamikdash was built?

Tags: korban

Are there other good characters in the tanach that built a mizbeach after the beit hamikdash had been built?

Comment: why do you ask specifically about tanakh?

Comment: @DoubleAA looking for reliable source.

Comment: I can think of other sources that I'd consider reliable besides tanakh. In any event PLEASE [edit] your question to clarify what you are looking for and why you are looking for it. You should _always_ be doing that to your questions to help others answer them better and to help you get what you want. This question is a prime example of how not explaining fully got you an answer you didn't want, thereby wasting the answerer's time, your time, and now my time. Do everyone a favor and please be clearer in the future.

Comment: Anyway, the answer is: no.

Comment: @DoubleAA is it Alice's fault that an answer was given that ignored her request for sources in Tanakh? It was a clearly stated requirement that was ignored by someone else that you are not currently haranguing.

Comment: @BSteinhurst Perhaps being hyperliteral here will pay off, but given the current form of the question I cannot fully blame answerers for citing other potentially useful classical examples. Tanakh is not in the title or the tags and no explanation for such an unusual choice is given. Sounds almost like the OP was just using the word to mean "old and authoritative". Besides, whether or not the current answer is anyone's fault, the current question is sufficiently poor to warrant requests for improvement. I mean, "Eliyahu" isn't even mentioned in the body of the question.

Comment: @DoubleAA the least we can we is take the question as written (hyper)literally. To do anything else is to impute unsupported intentions to a person neither you (unless I am mistaken) nor I (certain about this one) know.

Comment: @BSteinhurst While such a policy may seem reasonable _a priori_, I've seen too many questions where answering hyper-literally wastes everyone's time by not answering the intended question. So in practice, you have to use good sincere judgement. (I have never met the OP though I'm sure (s)he's a fine individual.)

Comment: Needs retagging. There's nothing in the question about _korbanos_.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/132203

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [Temple of Onias](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%A9_%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%95)

מקדש חוניו היה מרכז פולחן יהודי במצרים. הוא היה מבנה בצורת בית המקדש ובתוכו מזבח, שבנה חוניו בלאונטופוליס, אשר שכנה במחוז של העיר און (הליופוליס) במצרים. המקדש התגלה בחפירות הארכאולוגיות במשלחת בראשות הארכאולוג האנגלי פלינדרס פיטרי. החפירות התקימו בשנים 1905 - 1906.

This is not in t'nach since it was in the time of the second Bais ha-Mikdosh, but it is 'mentioned' in t'nach that one day there would be a  mizbeach in Egypt.

Comment: The OP asked for "good characters," and Chonyo's character was ambiguous at best. See the opinions of Rabbi Meir and Rabbi Yehuda in [*M'nachos* 109b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=30&daf=109b&format=text).

Comment: @Fred I appreciate what you write and I am new here. I am not sure that all answers have to 'exactly' answer the question.

Comment: Well then, @cham, allow me to welcome you to Mi Yodeya! Thanks for your contributions here thus far. You can familiarize yourself with this site by taking the [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour), and, more specifically, reading the page on [how best to answer questions here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Answers should ideally answer the precise question being asked. This answer is interesting, but, if it were me, I'd post it as a comment or include it in a more expanded answer since it doesn't precisely answer the question on its own.