# How do you make a Bamah?

Tags: halacha, mizbeach-altar, bamot

At certain points in Jewish history, private altars (Bamot) were permitted to use. I would like to know what requirements, if any, there were for something to be considered a Bamah.
For instance, did it have to be a certain size, made out of certain materials, designated as a private altar, located in a certain direction, etc. In effect, if there were a section in the code of Jewish law on private altars, what would it contain?

Comment: Isn't a Bamah essentially an unregulated altar?

Comment: @shmosel how do you make an unregulated altar?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/132203/korbonos-of-bnei-noach/

Comment: @rikitikitembo any structure intended to be used for sacrifices, I'd imagine.